# Unable to Implement custom MapHTTPRoute

Tags: c#, api

I am working on MobileAPI using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server where I have implemented controller class with multiple Get methods, but when I tried calling from Post Man only default get method is working.

Tried below setting in startup.MobileApp

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiWithActionName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

   [MobileAppController]
    public class CustomController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        //[ActionName("GetDifficultyOrderBY")]
        [Route("Custom/GetDifficultyOrderBY")]
        public List<TrainingDifficulty> GetDifficultyOrderBY()
        {
            List<TrainingDifficulty> trainingDifficultyList = null;
            using (var _dbcontext = new NarbisMobileAppContext()){
                trainingDifficultyList = _dbcontext.TrainingDifficulties.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
            }
            return trainingDifficultyList;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        //[ActionName("GetTrainingTimeOrderBY")]
        [Route("Custom/GetTrainingTimeOrderBY")]
        public List<TrainingTime> GetTrainingTimeOrderBY()
        {
            List<TrainingTime> trainingTimeList = null;
            using (var _dbcontext = new NarbisMobileAppContext())
            {
                trainingTimeList = _dbcontext.TrainingTimes.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Name)).ToList();
            }
            return trainingTimeList;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CustomController level add an attribute [RoutePrefix("api/Custom")] and remove 'Custom' from Route, i.e [Route("Custom/GetTrainingTimeOrderBY")] change this to [Route("GetTrainingTimeOrderBY")]

Now access it like *api/Custom/GetTrainingTimeOrderBY*

Hope this work.

Comment: Thanks,let me try